# Spring boot get flyway configuration

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am running flyway on spring boot and I need to get the baseline version from spring boot code. The baseline version I have set in my application.yml file as below

```
  flyway:
    enabled: false
    baseline-version: 3
```

And in my spring boot code I am intializing my flyway as below

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) {

    Flyway flywaysftp = Flyway.configure()
            .locations("classpath:db/migration/sftp")
            .baselineVersion(?)
            .dataSource(dataSourceConfigSftp.dataSourceSftp().getJdbcUrl(), dataSourceConfigSftp.dataSourceSftp().getUsername(), dataSourceConfigSftp.dataSourceSftp().getPassword()).load();
}
```

I need to be able to set the baseline version of flywaysftp to the baseline version in my application.yml.

Is there a way to retrieve the baseline version from my application.yml using flyway libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Spring @Value like this:

```
@Component
public class MyClass{

  @Value("${flyway.baseline-version}")
  private String flywayBaselineVersion;

 ....
 ....

public void run(String... args) {

    Flyway flywaysftp = Flyway.configure()
            .locations("classpath:db/migration/sftp")
            .baselineVersion(flywayBaselineVersion)
            .dataSource(dataSourceConfigSftp.dataSourceSftp().getJdbcUrl(), dataSourceConfigSftp.dataSourceSftp().getUsername(), dataSourceConfigSftp.dataSourceSftp().getPassword()).load();
}
}
```